# c++ char * initialization in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, char, initialization

I'm just curious, I want to know what's going on here:

```
class Test
{
char * name;
public:
Test(char * c) : name(c){}
};
```

1) Why won't `Test(const char * c) : name(c){}` work? Because `char * name` isn't const? But what about this:

```
main(){
char * name = "Peter";
}
```

`name` is char*, but `"Peter"` is const char*, right? So how does that initialization work?

2) `Test(char * c) : name(c){ c[0] = 'a'; }` - this crashes the program. Why?

Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: What do you mean `name(c)` doesn't work? Define "works".

Comment: @Eitan invalid conversion from const char* to char*

Comment: `"Peter"` is `const char[6]`, not `const char *`.

Comment: On a practical note, what you want instead is `std::string name`

Comment: @Peter this is for an exam, I don't think we're allowed to use std::string because it's not a part of the course

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why won't `Test(const char * c) : name(c) {}`  work? Because `char * name` isn't `const`?

Correct.

> how does this initialization work: `char * name = "Peter";`

A C++ string literal is of type `char const[]` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), as opposed to just `char[]` in C, as it didn't have the `const` keyword<sup>1</sup>). This assignment is considered deprecated in C++, yet it is still allowed<sup>2</sup> for backward compatibility with C.

> `Test(char * c) : name(c) { c[0] = 'a'; }` crashes the program. Why?

What are you passing to `Test` when initializing it? If you're passing a string literal or an illegal pointer, doing `c[0] = 'a'` is not allowed.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The old version of the C programming language (as described in the K&R book published in 1978) did not include the `const` keyword. Since then, [ANSI C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) borrowed the idea of `const` from C++.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Valid in C++03, no longer valid in C++11.</sup>

Comment: `char* c = "hello"; Test t(c);` or just `Test t("hello");` both crash

Comment: @tuks They better crash! The string literal "hello" cannot be modified, and you're trying to overwrite its first byte with `'a'`.

Comment: There _is_ a `const` keyword in C, and always was AFAIK (it's certainly in C89, and still in C11.)

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Since C89, but not in the original K&R C. I presume that's the reason why this is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

A conversion to `const` is a one-way street, so to speak.

You can convert from `T *` to `T const *` implicitly.

Conversion from `T const *` to `T *` requires an explicit cast. Even if you started from `T *`, then converted to `T const *`, converting *back* to `T *` requires an explicit cast, even though it's really just "restoring" the access you had to start with.

Note that throughout, `T const *` and `const T *` are precisely equivalent, and `T` stands for "some arbitrary type" (`char` in your example, but could just as easily be something else like `int` or `my_user_defined_type`).

Initializing a `char *` from a string literal (e.g., `char *s = "whatever";`) is allowed even though it violates this general rule (the literal itself is basically `const`, but you're creating a non-const pointer to it). This is simply because there's lots of code that depends on doing this, and nobody's been willing to break that code, so they have a rule to allow it. That rule's been deprecated, though, so at least in theory some future compiler could reject code that depends on it.

Since the string literal itself is basically `const`, any attempt at modifying it results in undefined behavior. On most modern systems, this will result in the process being terminated, because the memory storing the string literal will be marked at 'read only'. That's not the only possible result. Just for example, back in the days of MS-DOS, it would often succeed. It could still have bizarre side-effects though. For one example, many compilers "knew" that string literals were supposed to be read-only, so they'd "merge" identical string literals. Therefore if you had something like:

```
char *a = "Peter"; a[1] = 'a';

char *b = "Peter";

cout << b;
```

The compiler would have "merged" `a` and `b` to actually point at the same memory -- so when you modified `a`, that change would also affect `b`, so it would print out "Pater" instead of "Peter".

Note that the string literals didn't need to be entirely identical for this to happen either. As long as one was identical to the end of another, they could be merged:

```
char *a = "this?";
char *b = "What's this?";

a[2] = 'a';
a[3] = 't';

cout << b; // could print "What's that?"
```

Mandating one behavior didn't make sense, so the result was (and is) simply undefined.

Answer (score 2):

First of all this is C++, you have `std::string`. You should really consider using it.

Regarding your question, `"Peter"` is a char literal, hence it is unmodifiable and surely you can't write on it. You can:

- have a `const char *` member variable and initialize it like you are doing `name(c)`, by declaring `"Peter"` as `const`
- have a `char *` member variable and copy the content, eg `name(strdup(c))` (and remember to release it in destructor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct.
2. "Peter" is typically stored in a read-only memory location (actually, it depends on what type of device we are on) because it is a string literal. It is undefined what happens when you attempt to modify a string literal (but you can probably guess that you shouldn't).

You should use `std::string` anyways.

Answer (score -2):

1a) Right

1b) `"Peter"` is not `const char*`, its is `char*` but it may not be modified. The reason is for compatibility with times before `const` existed in the language. A lot of code already existed that said `char* p = "fred";` and they couldn't just make that code illegal overnight.

2) Can't say why that would crash the program without seeing how you are using that constructor.

Comment: Wrong. Who upvoted this? `"Peter"` is a `char const[6]`, not a `char*`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph if it's `char const[6]` then how is `char *name = "Peter";` legal?

Comment: 1) how come then this works: `Test(const char* c){ name = new char[strlen(c)+1]; strcpy(name,c);}` if i write `Test t("Peter");`, the constructor expects const char*, but `"Peter"` is char* ?

2) Test t("Hello");

Comment: @john It isn’t legal (in C++11; it’s legal but deprecated in C++03). A conforming compiler will warn you (in C++03) or reject the code (in C++11).